# '"entity_test" entity type does not exist' on attempted module uninstall

Tags: 8, entities, search

I'm in the process of replacing D8's core Search module with Search API. When I try uninstalling Search, I get this error:

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "entity_test" entity type does not exist. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:133

There is an entity_test table in the database, along with a number of related tables. I also have `$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = FALSE;` in the settings.local.php file.

How do I address this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you installed the entity_test module accidentally and then disabled test modules afterwards.

Set that flag to TRUE, clear cache, uninstall search and the entity_test module (look for other enabled _test modules too) then set that flag to FALSE again.

Comment: It looks like the entity_test module is part of the core, and I don't see any way to uninstall it via the UI. I attempted to uninstall it via drush and received a message that it was already uninstalled. So I tried to install it (again via drush) and received this message: `Configuration objects (core.entity_view_mode.entity_test.full,
core.entity_view_mode.entity_test.test) provided by entity_test
already exist in active configuration`

Comment: doesn't matter that it's part of core or not, it's just a module. That error sounds like it was installed at some point but probably half-uninstalled itself you disabled the test coverage. Possibly you have configurable fields created for those entity types. You could try to manually add the module to core.extension (with drush cedit for example) and then uninstall it properly.